# window.load document read does not run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple html5 page that renders a table with several rows. On two of the rows I gave a button that I want to act as a toggle button to show/hide a couple of other rows each.

The table is rendered intitally will all rows then I have a function that hides the 4 columns and sets the buttons to have the correct symbol.

When I run the page all the rows are visible... the window.load function does not run. I even tried document.ready and no joy. The toggle buttons once the inital click hides the rows functions correctly.

My code is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleRetail() {
        if ($('#but_RToggle').val()=="+"){
            $('#but_RToggle').val("-");
            $('#qretail').show("slow");
            $('#hretail').show("slow");
        } else {
            $('#but_RToggle').val("+");
            $('#qretail').hide("fast");
            $('#hretail').hide("fast");
        }        
    }

    function toggleWholesale() {
        if ($('#but_WToggle').val() == "+") {
            $('#but_WToggle').val("-");
            $('#qwholesale').show("slow");
            $('#hwholesale').show("slow");
        } else {
            $('#but_WToggle').val("+");
            $('#qwholesale').hide("fast");
            $('#hwholesale').hide("fast");
        }
    }

    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        $('#but_RToggle').val("+");
        $('#qretail').hide();
        $('#hretail').hide();
        $('#but_WToggle').val("+");
        $('#qwholesale').hide();
        $('#hwholesale').hide();
    });

</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `$(function() { ... }` and check if jquery is loaded

Comment: Do you load jquery before the script block you posted?

Comment: @MofX JQuery is referenced in my master page (this is a .net project) the script is loaded in the footer of the master page. I've not had any issues with other JQuery scripts that I have on the page including the toggle button click function I listed.

Comment: I did try $(document).ready... and it's shortcut $(function.... but no joy... I have even stuck a couple of alert statements at the beginning and end of the function and they don't fire. Weird.

Comment: Either share a url where this can be found, or make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the jquery script tag is before this script block.

For loading, any of these:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//code
});

$(function(){
//code
});

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
//code
},false);
```

Comment: $(window).bind("load", function() {...}); works as well, so this is not the problem

Comment: @MofX As mentioned in comment above jquery is reference in master page at the bottom. The script above is referenced in the contentplaceholder that would insert it in the head of the document. Is this OK... I'm just checking but I'm sure I have other $(document).ready scripts on other pages and they work fine.

Comment: Gents, thanks for all your replies.... I have moved the reference for jquery to the head section in my master page and all works fine. Even though on other pages where I used the same master page and similar .load function where it all worked fine. This page for some reason did not work until I moved the reference to load jquery befor the script above. Go figure!

Comment: Think about what's happening here when you have this code executing *before* jQuery is loaded: $(window). Javascript is looking for a function named $ to pass the window object to. $ doesn't exist yet. You may think your other pages are working like you expect, but I guarantee they are not.